# How can a process be blocking another process (that it spawned)?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, process, ravendb

I have written a utility program that is used to start and stop a specific process. Now, in testing it, it somehow seems to be blocking the process that it spawns!

It uses named system events (see [System.Threading.EventWaitHandle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Threading.EventWaitHandle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). After starting the process, it waits for the event to be set:

```
private static int StartRavenDB(string fileName, string workingDirectory, string arguments)
{
    var process = new Process
    {
        StartInfo =
        {
            FileName = fileName,
            WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory,
            Arguments = arguments,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true
        }
    };

    process.Start();

    var eventWaitHandle = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset, "StartStopRavenDBUtility");
    eventWaitHandle.Reset();

    eventWaitHandle.WaitOne();

    process.StandardInput.WriteLine("q");
    process.WaitForExit();

    return process.ExitCode;
}
```

Now, the RavenDB process that starts is a web server listening on `localhost:8080`.

Shortly after starting that process using the above utility, the process does not respond to web requests. It keeps timing out. As soon as I kill the utility process, everything starts to work normal.

For the record, I'm 100% the EventWaitHandle is not set yet - the RavenDB process is there, but it doesn't behave as it should.

I don't know what is happening or why, it's a completely separate process. What causes this problem?

Comment: What if you try subscribing to the `OutputDataReceived` event, as you are redirecting standard output? Maybe that will tell you something useful?

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you don't reset or wait on the event? For example, if instead of using the event, you sleep some 10 seconds, will you get the same behavior?

Comment: @Micke I will try your suggestion and let you know if I find something unusual.

Comment: @YacoubMassad Good suggestion, I will try.

Comment: @Micke I don't know why, but just adding an event handler + using `BeginOutputReadLine()` it actually does not block anymore... Actually I don't even need to attach an event. Calling `BeginOutputReadLine()` is enough! Oddly, I tried logging it to a file and it didn't work - but maybe I just suck at writing files in .NET :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should subscribe to the `OutputDataReceived` event or at least read the redirected standard output, to avoid blocking the thread. From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput(v=vs.110).aspx):

> These dependencies can cause deadlock conditions. When the caller
>   reads from the redirected stream of a child process, it is dependent
>   on the child. The caller waits for the read operation until the child
>   writes to the stream or closes the stream. **When the child process
>   writes enough data to fill its redirected stream, it is dependent on
>   the parent. The child process waits for the next write operation until
>   the parent reads from the full stream or closes the stream.** The
>   deadlock condition results when the caller and child process wait for
>   each other to complete an operation, and neither can continue. You can
>   avoid deadlocks by evaluating dependencies between the caller and
>   child process.

Comment: See my updated comment - it's not the event handler itself, it's really the `BeginOutputReadLine()` call :) Update your answer and I'll accept.

Comment: Actually, the documentation is pretty clear. Now I learned something.

Comment: wow, the documentation excerpt is a real shocker. Thanks for finding it! I wish I could upvote you thrice now.

Comment: I've seen the exact same behaviour in Python, so that's what gave me the clue.